# pandas groupby hour and calculate stockout time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a time series like below:

```
| datetime_create         | quantity_old | quantity_new | quantity_diff | is_stockout |
| 2018-02-15 08:12:54.289 | 16           | 15           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 08:14:10.619 | 15           | 13           | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 08:49:15.962 | 13           | 9            | -4            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 08:51:04.740 | 9            | 8            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 08:56:37.086 | 8            | 7            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 09:23:22.858 | 7            | 5            | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 10:16:50.324 | 5            | 4            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 10:19:25.071 | 4            | 3            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 10:33:22.788 | 3            | 2            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 10:33:34.125 | 2            | 0            | -2            | True        |
| 2018-02-15 16:45:24.747 | 0            | 1            | 1             | False       |
| 2018-02-15 16:48:29.996 | 1            | 0            | -1            | True        |
| 2018-02-17 10:42:58.325 | 0            | 42           | 42            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 10:47:07.380 | 42           | 41           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 11:42:31.008 | 41           | 40           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 11:48:31.070 | 40           | 39           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 12:39:13.681 | 39           | 38           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 12:48:00.286 | 38           | 37           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 12:56:59.203 | 37           | 36           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 13:18:12.285 | 36           | 35           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 13:29:53.465 | 35           | 34           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 14:54:55.810 | 34           | 33           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 15:53:38.816 | 33           | 32           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 16:28:08.076 | 32           | 31           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 16:45:18.965 | 31           | 30           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 16:59:11.111 | 30           | 29           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 17:18:53.646 | 29           | 27           | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 17:44:43.508 | 27           | 26           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 19:34:49.701 | 26           | 25           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 20:49:00.205 | 25           | 24           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 07:14:22.207 | 24           | 22           | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 08:35:41.560 | 22           | 20           | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 10:22:18.825 | 20           | 19           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 10:28:33.909 | 19           | 18           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 10:37:30.427 | 18           | 17           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 10:50:55.265 | 17           | 16           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 11:17:53.359 | 16           | 15           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 11:42:29.214 | 0            | 30           | 30            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 11:58:19.113 | 15           | 14           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 11:58:56.432 | 14           | 13           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 12:06:48.438 | 13           | 12           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 12:21:43.634 | 12           | 11           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 12:44:46.288 | 11           | 9            | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 13:26:01.952 | 9            | 8            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 13:26:40.940 | 8            | 9            | 1             | False       |
| 2018-02-18 13:27:34.090 | 9            | 8            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 13:27:52.443 | 8            | 9            | 1             | False       |
| 2018-02-18 13:28:58.832 | 9            | 8            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 14:56:49.105 | 8            | 7            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 16:00:32.212 | 7            | 6            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 16:28:20.175 | 6            | 5            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 16:31:48.741 | 5            | 3            | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 16:40:33.922 | 3            | 2            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 16:56:17.864 | 2            | 1            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 17:15:01.065 | 1            | 2            | 1             | False       |
| 2018-02-18 17:40:43.062 | 2            | 1            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 17:55:50.520 | 1            | 0            | -1            | True        |
| 2018-02-18 18:20:21.664 | 30           | 29           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-18 21:38:10.645 | 29           | 28           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-19 06:36:04.564 | 28           | 27           | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-19 08:49:23.080 | 27           | 26           | -1            | False       |
```

I want calculate the total stockout time in every hour in one day, like

```
|    date    |  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  | ... | 23  |
| ---------- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-02-15 | 10  | 0   | 0   | 10  | ... | 13  |
| 2018-02-16 | 6   | 0   | 7   | 10  | ... | 20  |
| 2018-02-17 | 6   | 0   | 0   | 10  | ... | 20  |
```

The rule:

1. group by hour
2. I can access all rows in an hour.
3. calculate time between

   - start point:  `is_stockout` from `False` to `True`
   - end point: `is_stockout` from `True` to `False`

   In an hour. 
   There may be many `start point` and `end point`
4. change index to day, and column to 24 hour.

It looks a little like [new-syntax-to-window-and-resample-operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#new-syntax-to-window-and-resample-operations)

I think I need use

```
df.resample('H').apply(caluclate_time_in_hour)
```

But this seems not enough:

1. `df.resample('H')` result index be hour, not column
2. How to write proper `caluclate_time_in_hour` ? I think `apply` can't do this.

   I wrote a pseudo-code:

   ```
   def caluclate_time_in_hour(item):
       # note: item here is stockcount . not just True or False

       global last_time
       global is_stockout
       global data

       cur_time = item.name

       # I need pandas return every row even that hour doesn't have data
       # so that no need to check the how many hours elasped.

       if item is np.nan:
           if is_stockout:
               data[cur_time.hour] = 60*60
           else:
               data[cur_time.hour] = 0

       if is_stockout:
           if item > 0:
               data[cur_time.hour] += cur_time - last_time
           else:
               is_stockout = False
       else:
           if item = 0:
               is_stockout = True

       last_time = item.name

       return data.copy()
   ```

   How to know this item is the last one in this hour , so that I can return the `data` ? This is the `apply` problem. Maybe I need pandas return all rows by hours to do apply.

I just wonder can I do above things by pandas built-in function, without looping all rows to  constuct the new DataFrame.

---

For example, `2018-02-15 ~ 2018-02-16` has below two records:

```
| datetime_create     | quantity_old | quantity_new | quantity_diff | is_stockout |
| 2018-02-14 00:45:00 | 40           | 10           | -30           | False       |
| 2018-02-15 12:45:00 | 10           | 2            | -8            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 13:45:00 | 2            | 1            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-15 16:45:00 | 1            | 0            | -1            | True        |
| 2018-02-16 10:42:00 | 0            | 42           | 42            | False       |
| 2018-02-16 13:42:00 | 42           | 40           | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-16 19:42:00 | 40           | 38           | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-17 20:42:00 | 38           | 40           | 2             | False       |
# duplicate above 
| 2018-02-18 00:45:00 | 40           | 10           | -30           | False       |
| 2018-02-19 12:45:00 | 10           | 2            | -8            | False       |
| 2018-02-19 13:45:00 | 2            | 1            | -1            | False       |
| 2018-02-19 16:45:00 | 1            | 0            | -1            | True        |
| 2018-02-20 10:42:00 | 0            | 42           | 42            | False       |
| 2018-02-20 13:42:00 | 42           | 40           | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-20 19:42:00 | 40           | 38           | -2            | False       |
| 2018-02-21 20:42:00 | 38           | 40           | 2             | False       |
```

csv:

```
datetime_create,quantity_old,quantity_new,quantity_diff,is_stockout
2018-02-14 00:45:00,40,10,-30,False
2018-02-15 12:45:00,10,2,-8,False
2018-02-15 13:45:00,2,1,-1,False
2018-02-15 16:45:00,1,0,-1,True
2018-02-16 10:42:00,0,42,42,False
2018-02-16 13:42:00,42,40,-2,False
2018-02-16 19:42:00,40,38,-2,False
2018-02-17 20:42:00,38,40,2,False
2018-02-18 00:45:00,40,10,-30,False
2018-02-19 12:45:00,10,2,-8,False
2018-02-19 13:45:00,2,1,-1,False
2018-02-19 16:45:00,1,0,-1,True
2018-02-20 10:42:00,0,42,42,False
2018-02-20 13:42:00,42,40,-2,False
2018-02-20 19:42:00,40,38,-2,False
2018-02-21 20:42:00,38,40,2,False
```

Would result (here time unit is minutes, for beauty) :

```
date,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
2018-02-14,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-02-15,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,15.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0
2018-02-16,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,42.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-02-17,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-02-18,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-02-19,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,15.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0
2018-02-20,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,60.0,42.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2018-02-21,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure with `df['s'] = df['is_stockout'].cumsum()` for start and end intervals, it is correct?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, I don't post all data structure at first.  There is stock quantity record   . `df['is_stockout'] ` is from `df['quantity_new'] ==0` . If  `quantity_new`  is `0`, then it is stockout. At first, I think post the two columns would make question more simple .

Comment: Thank you, is possible add some output expected values? `diff` is not easy count, but column `is_stockout` is possible?

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the question. My original data already has `diff` , don't need calculate.

Comment: Sorry, is possible add to sample 2 row DataFrame some another 2-3 rows with expected output?

Comment: @jezrael You are so polite. I add serveral rows, because there is no actual result , I have to I hand craft some.

Comment: Please chec edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need first [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by minutes with forward filling `NaN`s, convert to `inetger`s and for `Series` add  [`DataFrame.squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html).

Then aggregate by `date`s and `hour`s with `sum` and last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s = df[['is_stockout']].resample('T').ffill().astype(int).squeeze()
df1 = s.groupby([s.index.date, s.index.hour]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
datetime_create  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  14  15  16  17  \
2018-02-14        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   
2018-02-15        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0  15  60   
2018-02-16       60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 ...   0   0   0   0   
2018-02-17        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   
2018-02-18        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   
2018-02-19        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0  15  60   
2018-02-20       60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60  60 ...   0   0   0   0   
2018-02-21        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   

datetime_create  18  19  20  21  22  23  
2018-02-14        0   0   0   0   0   0  
2018-02-15       60  60  60  60  60  60  
2018-02-16        0   0   0   0   0   0  
2018-02-17        0   0   0   0   0   0  
2018-02-18        0   0   0   0   0   0  
2018-02-19       60  60  60  60  60  60  
2018-02-20        0   0   0   0   0   0  
2018-02-21        0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: WOW! I never thought could resample by minutes with ffill , that's a smart way. Thank you for your help.